# Bluetooth XBox controller not working with Pikuniku (GOG) on Mac

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, pikuniku

I'm trying to play Pikuniku (GOG version) on an Intel iMac Pro with Ventura (13.3.1).

I have an XBox Core controller (m1142084-007) connected with Bluetooth. The computer recognizes it and it appears to be fully functional. [Gamepad-tester](https://gamepad-tester.com/) shows all the buttons and sticks working, and other games I tried ("Asphalt8" and "Oddmar") have no problem. I have Pikuniku for Windows on a separate PC, and the same controller works fine when connected there.

But Pikuniku on the Mac completely ignores input from the controller. The only times it acknowledges the controller at all are:

- When I first open the game and it says "press any button", a button press on the controller works to move to the next screen
- When I go to Settings > Controls > Configure Controllers and press a button on the controller, it shows that a controller is connected. But that's it; subsequent pressed (even to hit "confirm") are ignored.

I can't find anything in the GOG forums about this specific issue. GOG does have a support entry for controllers not working on Macs in general, but all they recommend is making sure Steam isn't running (it's not installed). I contacted GOG support but so far (one week) no reply.

Has anyone successfully played Pikuniku on a Mac with a bluetooth controller? Is there something special I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Why not install Steam and see if that works? My guess is it only works in Steam because of Steam's controller virtualization.

Comment: @nondebug Hmm. I'm reluctant to buy yet another copy just to check. Also the [Steam page for Pikuniku](https://store.steampowered.com/app/572890/Pikuniku/) has a warning that it is not compatible with macOS 10.15 or above, apparently because it's a 32-bit binary. So it sounds like it wouldn't even run on current macOS?

Comment: You can add non-Steam games to Steam, no need to buy it again. If you launch the game from Steam then it can use Steam's controller virtualization even if you got the game somewhere else.